# Passing a function as a parameter in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm coding with Ionic/Angular.

I want to pass a function as a parameter to a function in another file, but the function doesn't get called.

alert.service.ts

```
  showAlertWithAction(header: string, message: string, action: () => void) {
    const alert = this.alertController.create({
      cssClass: 'custom-alert-ok',
      backdropDismiss: false,
      message,
      header,
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Okay',
        handler: () => action()
      }]
    });
    alert.then(createdAlert => createdAlert.present());
  }
```

The function gets called in another file:

some.page.ts

```
this.alertService.showAlertWithAction("Hello!", "Press Okay to close the modal", () => { this.closeModal() })
async closeModal() {
  await this.modalController.dismiss()
}
```

Comment: That's the correct way to pass it it but you an simplify the handler assignment line to: `handler: action` as the `action` signature already matches that of `handler` - no need to wrap it in another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to check:

1. Does `closeModal()` really need to be `async`? I imagine that `this.modalController.dismiss()` returns a promise, but you don't appear to need anything from that promise's return value (i.e. no `.then()`), so your function could look like this and still close your modal:

   ```
   closeModal(): void {
     this.modalController.dismiss()
   }
   ```
2. If point 1 is implemented, then `closeModal` becomes a function of the shape `() => void`. This is the same shape you wanted to pass to your `action` argument. The correct way to do this would be

   ```
   this.alertService.showAlertWithAction(
     "Hello!", "Press Okay to close the modal",
     this.closeModal  // Note: Do not include the brackets, this is now a function reference
   )
   ```
3. If you want to pass a function from one file to another, often you want to execute that function "with all the data from the original file". In other words you want to preserve that functions "execution context".

   For example, `this.modalController` is likely an instance of a
   service (or some other dependency) that is being passed into
   `some.page.ts`. When you pass `closeModal()` into another file, what you're really saying is "call `.dismiss()` on the instance of `modalController` that my `some.page.ts` had access to.

   In this case, we want the additional step of binding `some.page.ts`'s execution context to our method before passing it on:

   ```
   this.alertService.showAlertWithAction(
     "Hello!", "Press Okay to close the modal",
     this.closeModal.bind(this)
   )
   ```

Assuming all of the logic in your alert component is calling the `handler` method on your buttons correctly, the passed in method should now fire